# $stateProvider routing cannot locate view file using template URL

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular-ui-router

Using $stateprovider, I would like to retrieve my index.php and JavaScript files using a template URL. The view file is located at `resources/views/index.php` and my JavaScript file is located at `assets/js/app.js`. When accessing the template URL, the template files do not load.

Project structure:

```
|--resources
  |--assets
    |--js
       |--app.js
|--views
  |--index.php
```

my stateProvider:

```
.state("/", {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        '@':{
            templateUrl: '../../views/index.php',
        }
    },
    // controller: "Ctrl1"
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.state("/", {
    url: "/",
   templateUrl: '../../views/index.php',
    // controller: "Ctrl1"
  })
```